# Append Another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append another form-group.
The button at the form-group added is not working.
Can anyone tell me why?

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button class="add">Add</button>
 </div>
```

JS

```
 $('.add').click(function(){
 $('.form-group').append(
 '<input type="text"/>'+
 '<button class="add">Add</button>'
 );
})
```

Comment: have you tried separating the two elements with a comma, not a + sign?

Comment: SOrry, my fault, I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event delegation via [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements:

```
$('.form-group').on('click', '.add', function() {
  $('.form-group').append(
    '<input type="text"/>' +
    '<button class="add">Add</button>'
  );
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p1q90y3o/)**

Comment: That's it! Thanks! :)

Comment: This. JQuery is set up when the page loads, it reads every id and class that is selected by the JQuery selector and attaches the event to that element. If you make a new element it won't have the association.

Comment: it is possible to add a 'row' in div?

Comment: What do you mean by add a row?